# How to compile this project

Tags: java, android, import, compiler-errors

i am trying to compile this project  https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server
but it does not work.

I imported the project in Eclipse and created successfully the apk file but it gaves me an the following error:

"Error! Could not find daemon file,/data/data/org.onaips.vnc/lib/libandroidvncserver.so"

I think it is a matter of 2 minutes but i can't find the problem

Comment: Did you actually follow the build instructions? It says to run https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/blob/master/updateExecsAndLibs.sh which adds the library to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

check github , @krossovochkin Say to you  [here](https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/issues/87)

Looks like missing dependencies.
As a quick test, you can download droid-VNC-server.apk file, rename it to droid-VNC-server.zip, unpack this file. In /lib folder you should find libandroidvncserver.so compiled lib for every supported architecture.
You can add it to your project and try to build again.
This worked for me for commit: ac9c26d3c12396750c969e8e97c5c78e756a1dce

Another solution is to use commit: f95fa6bc44d4302acb2233d3c16f718d843ca33d
So there is no such a problem at all for me.

Hope it helps